# Volume in higher dimensions is well defined

Tags: real-analysis, volume

If $A=I_1\times\cdots\times I_n$, where the factors on the cross product are pairwise disjoint real intervals, define the volume of A by $vol (A)=length(I_1)\cdot\ldots\cdot length (I_n)$. On the other hand, if $B=A_1\cup\cdots\cup A_m$, where the terms of the union are pairwise disjoint cross products of real intervals (like as the set A), define the volume of B by $vol(B)=vol(A_1)+\cdots + vol (A_m)$. I’m trying to show that this notion of volume in higher dimensions is well defined, in the sense that if $B=\cup A_i$ and $B=\cup B_i$, then the volumes would be the same. Any ideas?

Comment: It clearly agrees with Lebesgue measure, which is well defined; QED.  Or are you doing this as an exercise?

Comment: Why are you requiring the $I_1,...,I_n$ to be pairwise disjoint?

Comment: @DanielMcLaury I'm doing as an exercise, I don't have much knowledge about the Lebesgue Measure yet.

Comment: @Thorgott Could this condition be dropped?

Comment: If I were to define a notion of volume, I would make sure to define it for a simple set such as the unit square $[0,1]\times[0,1]$ too.